# How to fix mass-assign protected attributes issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting an error saying Can't mass-assign protected attributes: product_id when I run the code in the controller below.
I've confirmed that @product does exist.  Any advice on how to fix this?

controller:

```
@product = Product.find(1)
a = Category.new(:category => 'Glasses', :product_id => @product.id)
a.save

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :blog
  has_many :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :category
    belongs_to :product
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing

```
@product = Product.find(1)
@product.categories.create(:category => 'Glasses')
```

is more elegant and should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :category, :product
    belongs_to :product
end
```

Then:

```
@product = Product.find(1)
a = Category.new(:category => 'Glasses', :product => @product)
a.save
```

Answer (score -1):

build it through the association

```
@product = Product.find(1)
a = @product.categories.new(:category => 'Glasses')
a.save
```

Since you don't have `attr_accessible :category, :product` in your category model